# Is WKB really applicable for the ground state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, perturbation-theory, semiclassical

It seems that WKB is applicable for a given $E$ if and only if $\hbar$ is sufficiently small. Or in other words, WKB is applicable if and only if the quantum number is large enough.

Is this understanding right?

I would take the exactness of WKB for the harmonic oscillator as purely accidental.

Comment: The exactnes of HO is not accidental. If you look at the evolution of the Wigner function in phase space, you see that only the *intial conditions*, not the evolution of the HO are quantum, and it is thus semi-classical in a perfectly well-defined way (...and now I'm going to dig in my stuff till I find that exact argument...)

Answer (score 1):

Comments to the question (v3):

1. *Yes,* given a Hamiltonian $H$, the semiclassical WKB method can give a qualitative but *not* a quantitative prediction for the ground state energy $E_0$.
2. The WKB prediction (incl. the [metaplectic correction](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/metaplectic+correction+%28in+geometric+quantization%29)/[Maslov index](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Maslov+index)) for the harmonic oscillator (HO) happens to be exact due to a hidden supersymmetry, cf. [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/162465/2451) Phys.SE post.
3. For an example where WKB is not exact, see e.g. my Phys.SE answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/147947/2451).

Answer (score 0):

The WKB approximation can be derived using an expansion in powers of $\hbar$. However, that doesn't imply that it can only be used if some quantum number is big. For example, a classic application of the WKB approximation is to alpha decay, which typically occurs from the ground state.

Comment: I have never understood the idea of expanding in a dimensioned parameter. "Expanding in $\hbar$" must certainly be expanding in $\hbar$ *divided by some action scale of the problem*, but nobody ever says this and certainly nobody ever seems to discuss what that action scale is.

Answer (score 0):

@DanielSank, for your question about "expanding in h_bar", please see the following explanation from http://www.tcm.phy.cam.ac.uk/~bds10/aqp/handout_approx.pdf.

[image: semiclassical_limit]