# Quasi-classical energies for neutron in gravitational potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, potential, neutrons, semiclassical, cold-atoms

Lets consider a ultra cold neutron gas in a gravitational potential. The known quasi-classical energy up to the classical turning point is

$$
E_n =\sqrt[3]{\frac{9m}{8}(\pi\hbar g (n-\frac{1}{4}))^2} 
$$
My question is that in this potential that has a vertical axis representing the potential $U(z)$ and $x$ horizontal axis representing the width of the well $z$, what would the potential be beyond the classical turning point?

[image]

Comment: Why edit out the image?

Comment: Similar potential: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/145892/2451

Answer (score 2):

Well, the form of the potential beyond the turning point depends on what's there.

When [Nesvizhevsky et al did this at ILL](http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v415/n6869/full/415297a.html), the lower surface was a neutron mirror, and the upper surface was an absorber.  (Actually I can't access that paper at the moment, so perhaps I'm misremembering; I'll correct if necessary.)

A good model for the mirror is a uniform Fermi pseudopotential of about 100 neV inside the mirror, and zero out; a good model for an absorber is a psuedopotential with a real part near zero, and a nonzero complex part which causes the neutrons to disappear as time evolves.

Note that the Nesvizhevsky-type experiments were with a collimated beam of UCNs, so that the part of their kinetic energy in the vertical direction was quite small compared to the "usual" UCN energy of 100 neV.  A "gas" suggests something more like the PNPI GraviTrap, which had no lid, and for which I don't believe there's been any evidence of quantized gravitational states.