# Why does the Bohr-Sommerfeld quantization for give the exact energy-levels for a harmonic oscillator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, supersymmetry, harmonic-oscillator, semiclassical

Why does the Bohr-Sommerfeld rule for quantization give the exact energy-levels for a simple harmonic oscillator?

Comment: Why shouldn't it? (Heuristically, you can see the Bohr-Sommerfeld quantization as arising from a WKB approximation that neglects all quantum effects of higher order than $\mathcal{O}(\hbar)$. It is then a "happy accident" that the quantum harmonic oscillator exhibits no quantum effects of higher orders, and exactly obeys the Bohr-Sommerfeld condition.)

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/129602/2451

Comment: I know, but one of my professors keeps saying that there is a physical reason behind that. It's not just an accident

Answer (score 3):

One can use various kinds of supersymmetry to argue that the WKB approximation for the [quantum harmonic oscillator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator) is exact. One method uses localization of path integrals, cf. e.g. Ref. 1. Another method uses supersymmetric quantum mechanics, cf. e.g. Ref. 2.

References:

1. R.J. Szabo, *Equivariant Localization of Path Integrals,* [hep-th/9608068](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9608068).
2. F. Cooper, A. Khare, and U. Sukhatme, *Supersymmetry and Quantum Mechanics,*     [Phys. Rept. 251 (1995) 267](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0370-1573(94)00080-M), [arXiv:hep-th/9405029](http://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9405029).

Answer (score -1):

It is one of rare cases when an approximate formula coincides with the exact one. Another example is the Plank formula obtained originally as a bridging of two experimental asymptotes. A fluke. There are some other cases of happy coincidents.