# Guess the wave function in a given potential

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, potential, ground-state

Are there any techniques in guessing the ground state wave function in any given potential?

For example, for a given potential like $$  \frac{1}{1-x^2}$$ or $$  \frac{1}{1-x^3}~?$$  I know wave function is sine or cosine inside the well and outside would be like exponential growth or decay depends on which side. Could I find the turning point by equating kinetic energy, $$ \frac{1}{2} m x'^2 ~?$$

Comment: Have a look at the WKB approximation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WKB_approximation#Application_to_the_Schr.C3.B6dinger_equation

Comment: Technically speaking, the WKB approximation is for highly exited states/continuum limit (rather than the ground state), cf. e.g. [this](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/129602/2451) Phys.SE post.